# Need help joining three table in sql using join method and concat method

Tags: mysql, sql, join, concatenation

There are three table as follow in which last table consist of two column from previous two table:

[image]

V:

[image]

I have completed the question with where clause but could not complete by join method. 
Here I did with where clause:

```
SELECT appointmentdate,doctorname,concat(name,' ',family) AS patientname 
from appointment,doctor,patients 
WHERE doctor.doctor_id=appointment.doctor_id 
AND appointment.patient_id=patients.patient_id;
```

Comment: what a awful question. you haven't put any effort to solve the issue atleast put some effort to post a proper question.

Comment: i did complete the question using where condition but cant complete using join method

Comment: Show something you tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.appointmentdate,
  d.doctorname,
  p.patientname
FROM appointment a
JOIN doctors d
ON a.doctor_id = d.doctor_id
JOIN patients p
ON a.patient_id = p.patient_id;
```

Comment: so in your answer a d p refer to table name appointment,doctors and patients right(Sorry just started learning  sql)

Comment: those are aliases for the table name. It'd highly inconvenient if we had to write the whole table name in front of every column like `appointment.appointmentdate`